# ffmpeg overlay a video after alphamerging two others

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion

I currently have this command to alphamerge two videos, and upscale one of them.

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i matte.mp4 -filter_complex '[1][0]scale2ref[mask][main];[main][mask]alphamerge' -c:v qtrle output.mov
```

I also have this command to overlay a video ontop of another

```
ffmpeg -i background.mp4 -i output.mov -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay[out]" -map [out] complete.mp4
```

What I'm trying to do is combine them into one command, so it takes the `video.mp4`, applies the `matte.mp4` with alphamerge, and places it over the `background.mp4`

but I'm unsure how to reference the third input in a command, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

`ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i matte.mp4 -i background.mp4 -filter_complex '[1][0]scale2ref[mask][main];[main][mask]alphamerge[vid];[2:v][vid]overlay[out]' -map [out] complete.mp4`

Comment: Could you explain in a little more detail what this command does?

Comment: @Burgi Filter docs are at https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html.

Comment: @JasonC my comment was meant as a hint to the OP to improve their answer. It came up in review as low quality.