# ffmpeg overlay image into video after alphamerging

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-conversion

I currently have two videos, `word.mp4` and `word.matte.mp4`.  I'm trying to `alphamerge` these two videos with an `image.jpg` overlay.

The command I'm trying to use, which I tweaked from [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1649817/ffmpeg-overlay-a-video-after-alphamerging-two-others/1649856#1649856), is giving me an error

```
ffmpeg -i word.mp4 -i word.matte.mp4 -i image.jpg -filter_complex '[1][0]scale2ref[mask][main];[main][mask]alphamerge[vid];[2:v][vid]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2[out]' -map [out] complete.mp4
```

but I get this error

```
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (hevc) -> scale2ref:ref
  Stream #1:0 (mpeg4) -> scale2ref:default
  Stream #2:0 (mjpeg) -> overlay:main
  overlay -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x560faabe37c0] width not divisible by 2 (983x1115)
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
Conversion failed!
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both width and height of the final output need to be even for widely-compatible playback. In this case, those dimensions are the same as the JPEG input.

The quickest way is to resize the JPEG.

```
ffmpeg -i image.jpeg -vf "scale=bitand(iw+1,65534):bitand(ih+1,65534)" -q:v 2 new.jpg
```

Comment: is there any way to auto scale the jpeg? As I'm unsure what the size of the videoes are going to be

Comment: `ffmpeg -i image.jpeg -i word.mp4 -filter_complex "scale2ref[img][vid];[img]setsar=1;[vid]nullsink" -q:v 2 new.jpg`