# ffmpeg automatically scale image then overlay video onto image in one step

Tags: ffmpeg, video, images, video-conversion

After asking [this question](https://superuser.com/a/1649961/535078), it was suggested that the best way to do this would be scale the image, with this command.

```
ffmpeg -i image.jpeg -i word.mp4 -filter_complex "scale2ref[img][vid];[img]setsar=1;[vid]nullsink" -q:v 2 new.jpg
```

At which point I am a bit confused as how I would then overlay the `video.mp4` over the `new.jpg`.  I'm certain I need to run a second ffmpeg command, similar to this one

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i new.jpg -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease[fg];[1][fg]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2" output.mp4
```

But I believe this command is scaling the video, even though i just previously scaled the image, and also this would be two ffmpeg commands, instead of just one that autoscales the image to match the aspect of the video.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Use

`ffmpeg -i image.jpeg -i word.mp4 -i video.mp4 -filter_complex "[0][1]scale2ref[img][vid];[img]setsar=1[img];[vid]nullsink; [img][2]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2" output.mp4`

The video isn't scaled in this command, only overlaid on top of the resized image.

Comment: your command works, but now how I was hoping.  It places the image, the matte key file, not the transparent one.  And the matte key file, is tiny.  So to clarify, I have two videos and an image.  One is the original, one is the matte file, one is an image.  I would like the matte key to alpha merge with the video, leaving the origianl video without a background, then have that video overlayed over an image, scaled appropriately.

Comment: and I switched the input order, it then shows the overlay massive.  So almost there