# ffmpeg overlay and auto scale a video after alphamerging two others

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-conversion

I had asked [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1649817/ffmpeg-overlay-a-video-after-alphamerging-two-others) on how to overlay a alphamerged video over another, and got answered this command.  I tweaked it a bit, to add in the shortest for the overlay, to have it be only as long as the shorest part.

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i matte.mp4 -i background.mp4 -filter_complex '[1][0]scale2ref[mask][main];[main][mask]alphamerge[vid];[2:v][vid]overlay=shortest=1[out]' -map [out] complete.mp4
```

This works, but I needed to be a bit more specific, how would I modify this command, to have it auto scale the alphamerged video to the size of the video its overlaying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another [scale2ref](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale2ref):

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i matte.mp4 -i background.mp4 -filter_complex '[1][0]scale2ref[mask][main];[main][mask]alphamerge[vid];[vid][2:v]scale2ref[fg][bg];[bg][fg]overlay[out]' -map [out] complete.mp4
```

- The first scale2ref makes `matte.mp4` the same size as `video.mp4`.
- The second scale2ref makes the alphamerge output the same size as `background.mp4`.